# Regular expression for match string within first five words of input sentence

Tags: regex, regular-language

I want to match specific strings from beginning to 5th word of article title.

Input string:

```
The 14 best US colleges in the West are dominated by California — here's who makes the cut.
```

regex:

```
/^.*(\bbest\b|\btop\b|\bhot\b).*$/
```

Currently matched whole article title but want to search till "colleges".
and also need ignore or not matched strings like laptop,hot-spot etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this expression

```
^((?:\w+\s?){1,5}).*
```

Explanation:

`^` assert position at start of the string

`\w+` match any word character

`\s?` match any white space character

`{1,5}` Quantifier - Between 1 and 5 times, as many times as possible

`.*` matches any character (except newline)

This matches the first 5 words (and spaces).

Comment: How can i ignore to match %,$ or any special character and also length of numeric string is less than 4. Need to ignore following types of senstense. 1. 3D Print a LED Matrix Display. 2. 2016 LIFT Scholarship Winner Luis Camacho Caballero. 3. $15 is the new price for mobile cover. @manaR

Comment: I guess you could match these strings first , exclude them from your file and then do the normal matching?

Answer (score 0):

```
^(\w+\s){0,4}\b(best|top|hot)(\s|$)
```

You want to match string within first five words of input sentence. Then if counted from the start the sentence, there must be 0-4 words before the word you want to match. So you need `^(\w+\s){0,4}` before the specific words you want to match. See https://regex101.com/r/nS0dU6/4

Comment: Thanks works perfect but can i use + or any other operator instead of comma in {0,4}.

Comment: @santosh I don't quite get what you mean by "use + or any other operator instead of comma in {0,4}".

Answer (score 0):

[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/sK2zA0/2) comes to help again.

`^(?=(?:\w+\s){0,4}?(?:best|top|hot)\b(?!-))(\w+(?:\s\w+){0,4})`

- `(?=(?:\w+\s){0,4}?(?:best|top|hot)\b(?!-)` checks that the keyword is within first 5 (note that `(?!-)` is added to cater for words such as `hot-spot`)
- `(\w+(?:\s\w+){0,4})` then matches the first maximum 5 words

Comment: Thanks works perfect but can i use + or any other operator instead of comma in {0,4}.

Comment: I don't think so. Why?

Comment: How can i ignore to match %,$ or any special character and also length of numeric string is less than 4. Need to ignore following types of senstense. 1. 3D Print a LED Matrix Display. 2. 2016 LiFT Scholarship Winner Luis Camacho Caballero. 3. $15 is the new prise for mobile cover.

Comment: Change `\w` to something like `[A-Za-z]`